# How to ignore prefix in spring view resolver

Tags: java, spring, jsp

this is how i prefix the location of my jsps

```
  <bean id="viewResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
   p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
   p:prefix="/WEBINF/other/views/"
   p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

in my controller i use

```
protected String renderDefault(RenderRequest request, Model model)
{
   return "view";
}
```

Is there anyway i could return an absolute path such as

```
return "/WEBINF/common/thisView"
```

I know i could use ../common/thisView to get to the correct jsp but this could cause issues if the classpath where to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`UrlBasedViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html):

> View names can either be resource URLs themselves, or get augmented by a specified prefix and/or suffix.

You could give back the absolute path.

To avoid returning the absolute path everywhere, you could define multiple `ViewResolver` (in your case multiple `InternalResourceViewResolver`) using the `order` attribute to define the resolution order. [ViewResolvers can be chained](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html).

Comment: I ended up overwriting the buildView method within the InternalResourceViewResolver just checking if the view name started with a / if it did i removed the prefix...not the way i wanted to do it but it works